# C# syntax for unordered_map

Tags: c#

I am struggling to convert the below C++ code to an equivalent C# function, and I must admit that I have no experience with C++. I would really appreciate some help in this conversion.

To be specific:

1. I understand that unordered_map is a dictionary in C# but whats the equivalent for `strings( (max_code * 11) / 10 )` that is passed in  the declaration?
2. What is the equivalent for `INPUT &input, OUTPUT &output` in C#? - I want to pass a byte array to this function and return a byte array.

Thanks...

```
void decompress( INPUT &input, OUTPUT &output, const unsigned int max_code = 32767  )
{
    input_code_stream<INPUT> in( input, max_code );
    output_symbol_stream<OUTPUT> out( output );

    std::unordered_map<unsigned int,std::string> strings( (max_code * 11) / 10 );
    for ( int unsigned i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ )
        strings[i] = std::string(1,i);
    std::string previous_string;
    unsigned int code;
    unsigned int next_code = 257;
    while ( in >> code ) {
        if ( strings.find( code ) == strings.end() ) 
            strings[ code ] = previous_string + previous_string[0];
        out << strings[code];
        if ( previous_string.size() && next_code <= max_code )
            strings[next_code++] = previous_string + strings[code][0];
        previous_string = strings[code];
   }
}
```

Comment: @user3363391 learn C++ before trying to convert anything. Otherwise you'll end up creating extremely complex and slow code that does in 10 lines what coud be done in only 1.

Comment: @user3363391 given the name of the method, `decompress`, you should understand the algorithm, not try to blindly convert method calls.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first one

There's no direct equivalent to `strings( (max_code * 11) / 10 )` in C#. Since C# bases its buckets on the size equal to the first prime number (From their magic prime number list (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,19337ead89202585,references)) that's greater than the amount of elements in the dictionary. In C++ you specify the minimum amount of buckets in your map.

To achieve something close to it in C#, you can use the `capacity` parameter of the dictionary's constructor to specify the minimum capacity of the dictionary.

However you have to keep in mind that the amount of buckets still won't be the amount you expect to get from C++. Ex.

Let's assume `max_code` is 12.

```
strings( (max_code * 11) / 10 )
```

would have 13 buckets.

However in C# the following

```
new Dictionary<int,string>(capacity: (max_code * 11) / 10);
```

would have 17 buckets.